# Target class [ProductController] does not exist. laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

i am creating a simple crud using  laravel crud 5.8 i ran in to the problem with Target class [ProductController] does not exist. what i tried so far i attached below.

**ProductController**

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('products.index',compact('products'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }


    public function create()
    {
        return view('products.create');
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
        ]);

        Product::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
            ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
```

**index.blade.php**

```
 @extends('products.layout')
 
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 5.8 CRUD Example from scratch - ItSolutionStuff.com</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('products.create') }}"> Create New Product</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

      
        {!! $products->links() !!}
          
    @endsection
```

**File structure**
[image]

i added the view page above

Comment: Do you have a `namespace` set in your **RouteServiceProvider.php**

Comment: namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;            RouteServiceProvider.php these namespaces has

Comment: `Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;` Are you using Laravel `5.8` or `8` ? There's a difference

Comment: 5.8 sirr..................................

Comment: shall i send a project to u

Comment: email pls sir...................

Comment: Try with command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: `Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit` this has been introduced with [Laravel 8](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v8.0.3/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) with Laravel 5.8 the file should [look like this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.8.35/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) and As you can see, there's a default namespace set. Since Laravel 8, this as become optional and it's [preferable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing) to use namespace in your **web.php**,

Comment: Agree with Clément Baconnier, its probably 8.x, try with `Route::resource('products','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController');`

Comment: ya i did what u said sir again i got the diffrent error View [products.index] not found

Comment: From your screenshot I see that you have `views/index.blade.php` but `products.index` expect `views/products/index.blade.php`

Comment: On your controller index function, change `products.index` to `index`

Comment: Anyway, its not *laravel 5.8*, its **Laravel 8**

Comment: sit i have created the product folder and put now index page is working file. when i click the create product button it goes to the product page successfully but after fill the form and click submit button it shown the error Add [_token] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Product].

Comment: I believe you're following a tutorial for Laravel 5.8 but I **strongly** believe that you're using Laravel 8. You can follow most of the tutorial. But just keep in mind that there's some changes since then and if something doesn't work, try first to see how we do it with Laravel 8, it will be a good excerice

Comment: which one is good larvel 8 or 5.8

Comment: `Product::create($request->all());` this should be `Product::create($request->validated());` to only get ['name', 'detail'] `all()` will allow the user to send extra fields and will be saved. You don't want that.

Comment: i am a beginner of laravel

Comment: Laravel 5.8 is no longer supported https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#support-policy But you're aready using Laravel 8, which is good

Comment: Did you declare the namespace correctly in the Controller? namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**routes**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('products','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController');
```

**And make folder in resource / views / products / index.blade.php**